# Circular linked list: How to correct my remove node function?

Tags: c++, circular-list

I am learning circular linked list. I face a problem when calling `deleteNodeByKey()` to remove head node. It works for the rest of the nodes for remove. Why is it not working if remove node is head?

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

/* structure for a node */
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

/* Function to insert a node at the begining of a Circular
   linked list */
void push(struct node **head_ref, int data)
{
    struct node *ptr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    ptr->data = data;
    ptr->next = *head_ref;
    struct node *temp = *head_ref;
     /* If linked list is not NULL then set the next of last node. 
        It is going to last node by circling 1 times.
     */
    if(*head_ref != NULL){
        while(temp->next != *head_ref){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        //set last node by ptr
        temp->next = ptr;
    }
    else{
        // 1 node circular linked list
        ptr->next = ptr;
    }
    // after push ptr is the new node
    *head_ref = ptr;
}

//get the previous node
struct node* getPreviousNode(struct node* current_node){
    struct node* prev = current_node;
    while(prev->next != NULL && prev->next->data != current_node->data ){
        prev = prev->next;
    }
    return prev; 
}


/* Given a reference (pointer to pointer) to the head of a list
   and a key, deletes the first occurrence of key in linked list */
void deleteNodeByKey(struct node **head_ref, int key)
{
    // Store head node
    struct node* current_node = *head_ref, *prev;


    while(current_node != NULL && current_node->data != key){
        current_node = current_node->next;   
    }

    if(current_node == NULL){
        return;
    }

    //Removing the node
    if(current_node->data == key){
        prev = getPreviousNode(current_node);
        prev->next = current_node->next; 
        current_node->next = NULL;
        free(current_node);               
        return;
    }
}


/* Function to print nodes in a given Circular linked list */
void printList(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *temp = head;
    if(head != NULL){
        /*
            do-while because at 1st temp points head 
            and after 1 rotation temp wil come back to head again
        */
        do{
            cout<<temp->data<<' ';
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        while(temp != head);
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main() {
     /* Initialize lists as empty */
    struct node *head = NULL;
    /* Created linked list will be 11->2->56->12 */
    push(&head, 12);
    push(&head, 56);
    push(&head, 2);
    push(&head, 11);
    cout<<"Contents of Circular Linked List"<<endl;
    printList(head);

    deleteNodeByKey(&head, 11);
    printList(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code link: [Source Code](http://ideone.com/lvJr9K)

Comment: And what problem are you facing?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @user5005768 Tag says C++, but the code looks like C. You might want to correct one or the other.

Comment: Look for the place where you assign a value to `*head_ref`.

Comment: Note the "Minimal" in MCVE.  You don't need the print or delete or anything else.

Comment: Note also the [‘specific problem or error’](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside deleteNodeByKey() function i add an if() block to re assign head node to it's next node:

```
 //Removing the node
    if(current_node->data == key){
        //following if() is newly added
        //key is inside head node
        if(current_node == *head_ref ){
            //changing the head point to next
            *head_ref = current_node->next;
        }
        prev = getPreviousNode(current_node);
        prev->next = current_node->next; 
        current_node->next = NULL;
        free(current_node);               
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Head node should not be the part of linked list, it should be a separate node which holds the address of the first node of the linked list. So when yo delete the first node make the Head point to the next of the first node and when you follow this structure the head-node will be same like other nodes.
[image]

**declare head like this:**

```
struct node* head;
head = *first;
```

**To delete first**

```
head = head->next;
free(first);`
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get around issues pertaining to deletion of head. I always found it useful to create a dummy node and set your head pointer to that.

```
node dummy;
dummy.next = *head_ref;

// Store head node
struct node* current_node = &dummy, *prev = &dummy;
current_node = current_node->next;
```

Once you are done with the operation set the head back to dummy.next. In this way you no longer need to keep track of the special case head, it can be treated as a normal node. Your code modified here: [deletion with dummy node](http://ideone.com/HQhZk4)